# Numpy: Apply function pairwise on two arrays of different length

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make use of numpy vectorized operations. But I struggle on the following task: The setting is two arrays of different length (X1, X2). I want to apply a method to each pair (e.g. X1[0] with X2[0], X2[1], etc). I wrote the following working code using loops, but I'd like to get rid of the loops.

```py
result = []
for i in range(len(X1)):
    result.append([])
    for j in range(len(X2)):
        tmp = my_method(X1[i] - X2[j])
        result[i].append(tmp)
result = np.asarray(result)
```

Comment: what is "my_method"?

Comment: It's another function I declared elsewhere. In theory I want this to work with any function

Comment: the solution will depend on the required operation. it might not always be the same.

Comment: That's a bummer. I was hoping there was something like `np.apply_pairwise`

Comment: try `np.ufunc.outer` I'm drunk

Comment: @CEN, you might not want to use a vectorized solution. if your operation is self-contained, then you can just use numba to accelerate your code as is. sometimes this is faster than numpy's solution or that of another package. it's certainly faster than itertools

Answer (score 2):

You can `reshape` one of your vectors to be `(N, 1)` and then use `vectorize` which will broadcast the operation as normal:

```
import numpy as np

X1 = np.arange(5)
X2 = np.arange(3)
print(X1, X2)
# [0 1 2 3 4] [0 1 2]

def my_op(x, y):
  return x + y

np.vectorize(my_op)(X1[:, np.newaxis], X2)
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [1, 2, 3],
#        [2, 3, 4],
#        [3, 4, 5],
#        [4, 5, 6]])
```

Note that `my_op` is just defined as an example; if your function is actually anything included in numpy's vectorized operations, it'd be much faster to just use that directly, e.g.:

```
X1[:, np.newaxis] + X2
```

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) might be what you're looking for:

```py
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array(...)
x2 = np.array(...)
result = np.array([my_method(x_1 - x_2) for x_1, x_2 in product(x1,x2)])
```

Alternatively you could also use a double list comprehension:

```py
result = np.array([my_method(x_1 - x_2) for x_1 in x1 for x_2 in x2])
```

This obviously depends on what `my_method` is doing and operating on and what you have stored in `x1` and `x2`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a simple function `my_method(a, b)`, which adds the two numbers.

And this input:

```
X1 = np.arange(10)
X2 = np.arange(10,60,10)
```

You code is:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(X1)):
    result.append([])
    for j in range(len(X2)):
        tmp = my_method(X1[i], X2[j])
        result[i].append(tmp)
result = np.asarray(result)
```

You can replace it with broadcasting:

```
X1[:,None]+X2
```

output:

```
array([[10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
       [11, 21, 31, 41, 51],
       [12, 22, 32, 42, 52],
       [13, 23, 33, 43, 53],
       [14, 24, 34, 44, 54],
       [15, 25, 35, 45, 55],
       [16, 26, 36, 46, 56],
       [17, 27, 37, 47, 57],
       [18, 28, 38, 48, 58],
       [19, 29, 39, 49, 59]])
```

Now you need to see if your operation can be vectorized… please share details on what you want to achieve. Functions can be vectorized using `numpy.vectorize`, but this is not a magic tool as it will loop on the elements, which can be slow. The best is to have a true vector operation.